# Five-letter English word that contains only two distinct letters

Tags: english

Is there any 5-letter English word that uses only 2 distinct letters?

Comment: Did you make this puzzle? I am pretty sure this site is for puzzles you made only. Are you even sure this exists?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck - Actually externally sourced puzzles are "fine", although preferably with citation, and preferably not ones that have solutions pasted all over the net, or are just poor quality. There is a tag for unsolved-mysteries, for example. This does not seem to be everywhere or to be of poor quality (or an unsolved mystery of course), although a couple of words for close relations spring to mind pretty quickly (ease != poor quality).

Comment: @JonathanAllan true, but a user shouldnt just randomly make something up and expect an answer. From my perspective this seems like a random question. This is a new user and I believe this question is spam.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Clearly this is not spam, there is a specific question and no link. You might debate it being off-topic. Also, the user is active on a few other SE sites, so I imagine they thought this would be the correct stack to ask this question on, rather than, say, English.SE and have not just come here to post a "random" question.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: I dunno what counts as "spam" here, but I'm definitely a human being who is very active on various SE sites. I happened to need an answer to this question, and this was the best resource I could think of for getting the question answered (as indeed it proved to be, as I promptly got answers). I seem to have caused great inconvenience and distress by posing this question. So please do accept my sincere apologies.

Comment: @KennyLJ not blatant spam. I simply felt that the question was off topic as it had no unique solution. No problem man. I guess not all questions have to be puzzles on here. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This regex dictionary](http://www.puzzlers.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=solving:wordlists:dictionary_search) returns 34 matches. I removed the ones that were proper nouns or that I couldn't find definitions of:

`ajaja`: species name of the [roseate spoonbill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roseate_spoonbill)?
`alala`: [ʻalalā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_crow), a Hawaiian crow.
`anana`: alternate name for a pineapple?
`arara`: a [palm cockatoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm_cockatoo).
`cocco`: a taro tuber.
`esses`: plural of "ess", the letter S.
`hoooo`: transliteration of Japanese [鳳凰](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%B3%B3%E5%87%B0#Japanese) (phoenix).
`mamma`: alternative spelling of "mama", or a mammary gland.
`nanna`: a word for a grandmother.
`pappa`: a word for a father.
`susus`: plural of ["susu"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susu_(informal_loan_club)), a money sharing group.
`taata`: a word for a father.
`tatta`: a bamboo frame.
`uhhuh`: (usually hyphenated) an affirmative response.
`ululu`: a wail.
`unnun`: to cause someone to stop being a nun.
`xxiii`: Roman numerals for 23 (32, 39, 41, etc. weren't listed but would also work the same).

Comment: What's the regex for that?

Comment: Thanks. I think MAMMA is the one word that comes closest to qualifying as an "English word".

Comment: @Carl `^([a-z])\1*([a-z])(\1|\2)*$` with the length restricted to 5 produces that list.

Comment: Anti-Wordle players from the future are grateful for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Some I can think of are:

> [ESSES](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/esses), the plural of ess (the letter S)
>  [MAMMA](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mamma), "a mammary gland and its accessory parts"